# download pdf files from using curl

Tags: wget, curl, bash-script

How to  download  hundereds of .pdf files from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles using a loop, for example for the following document ids:

```
PMC3386155
PMC3625956
PMC3477654
PMC3531051
PMC3114846
PMC3117879
PMC3130560
PMC3531173
PMC3546115
PMC3354575
PMC3771521
```

Comment: Are these open access or do you have to enter your institution's credentials every time?

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83687/using-wget-to-get-file-names-from-a-text-file/83698#83698

Comment: pubmed Q: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91696/how-to-download-pdf-files-from-pubmed. Why is this one different?

Comment: @sami have you checked that script ? is there any issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is Working Tested Script

**Using wget**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Link="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/"

ID=(    PMC3386155 PMC3625956 PMC3477654 PMC3531051
        PMC3114846 PMC3117879 PMC3130560 PMC3531173
        PMC3546115 PMC3354575 PMC3771521 )

for f in ${ID[@]};
do
   wget  --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" \
         -l1 --no-parent -A.pdf ${Link}${f}/pdf/ -O ${f}.pdf
done
```

Since Remote site does not allow user agent like `wget` and `curl`  that's why we have to explicitly specify user agent in `wget`

**Using Curl**

```
ID=( PMC3386155 PMC3625956 PMC3477654 PMC3531051 PMC3114846 PMC3117879 PMC3130560 PMC3531173 PMC3546115 PMC3354575 PMC3771521 )

Link="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/"

Args='-O -J -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"'

printf "%s\n" ${ID[@]}  | xargs -n1 -I{} echo curl $Args ${Link}'{}'/pdf/ | sh
```

**Some explanation**

- **-O**  Output File
- **-J**  Output File name from remote-header-name ( `curl 7.21.2` or newer )
- **-L**  Remote site redirected to other download page to follow that use this
- **-A**  User agent